# String manipulation in ada

Tags: string, ada

I am getting a path of directory in a string , like `"C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Hello”`, and I am trying to get the last directory, but without success.

I tried a lot of manipulation on the string but in the end of the day i stayed with nothing... i will be grateful to get some help. Thanks !

Here was my first idea :

```
Get_Line(Line, Len);
while (Line /="") loop
   FirstWord:=Index(Line(1..Len),"\")+1;
   declare
      NewLine :String := (Line(FirstWord .. Len));
   begin
      Line:=NewLine ; 
   end;
end loop;
```

I know its not working (I can’t assign `NewLine` to `Line` because there isn't a match between their lengths), and now I am stuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’m assuming you want to manipulate directory (and file) names, rather than just any old string?

In which case you should look at the standard library packages `Ada.Directories` ([ARM A.16](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-16.html)) and `Ada.Directories.Hierarchical_File_Names` ([ARM A.16.1](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-16-1.html)):

```ada
with Ada.Directories;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Tal is
   Line : constant String := "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Hello";
begin
   Put_Line ("Full_Name: "
               & Ada.Directories.Full_Name (Line));
   Put_Line ("Simple_Name: "
               & Ada.Directories.Simple_Name (Line));
   Put_Line ("Containing_Directory: "
               & Ada.Directories.Containing_Directory (Line));
   Put_Line ("Base_Name: "
               & Ada.Directories.Base_Name (Line));
end Tal;
```

On the other hand, if you’re trying to work out plain string manipulation, you could use something like

```ada
with Ada.Strings.Fixed;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Tal is

   function Get_Last_Word (From : String;
                           With_Separator : String)
                          return String is
      Separator_Position : constant Natural :=
        Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index (Source => From,
                                 Pattern => With_Separator,
                                 Going => Ada.Strings.Backward);
   begin
      --  This will fail if there are no separators in From
      return From (Separator_Position + 1 .. From'Last);   --'
   end Get_Last_Word;

   Line : constant String := "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Hello";

   Last_Name : constant String := Get_Last_Word (Line, "\");

begin
   Put_Line (Last_Name);
end Tal;
```

As you can see, putting the logic in `Get_Last_Word` allows you to hoist `Last_Name` out of a `declare` block. But it will never be possible to overwrite a fixed string with a substring of itself (unless you’re prepared to deal with trailing blanks, that is): it’s much better never to try.